# Getting Django 500 errors flagged by sentry

Tags: python-3.x, django, sentry

We are paying for sentry, but evidently that doesn't qualify us for timely support.  I've created a minimum reproduction [repo](https://github.com/boatcoder/sentry-problem). This case has been open with them for a couple of days now but they just aren't responding.

running `runserver` with `settings.DEBUG=0` and `sentry_sdk.debug=True`

Basically what happens is that this:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 20, 2023 - 22:51:50
Django version 4.1.7, using settings 'sentry_problem.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
 [sentry] DEBUG: [Tracing] Adding `sentry-trace` header 4aa953c03dfa443cb06e0f0ecd8bedf2-b08d08fd5102560a- to outgoing request to https://o976653.ingest.sentry.io/api/4504707199270912/store/.
 [sentry] DEBUG: [Tracing] Discarding <http.server> transaction <generic WSGI request> because traces_sample_rate is set to 0
ERROR - [2023-02-20 22:52:02] - blowup.views.boom:10 - This is before the boom
 [sentry] DEBUG: Sending event, type:null level:error event_id:f2cdc3f26dd24509929e1129558116bf project:4504707199270912 host:o976653.ingest.sentry.io
 [sentry] DEBUG: [Tracing] Adding `sentry-trace` header f8e5e532ef6a4a7b90d634fb1bda417f-b540c108bc09311b-0 to outgoing request to https://o976653.ingest.sentry.io/api/4504707199270912/store/.
 [sentry] DEBUG: [Tracing] Adding `baggage` header sentry-trace_id=f8e5e532ef6a4a7b90d634fb1bda417f,sentry-environment=production,sentry-release=20dadf61a55e11789e96ad7171fd17445baee6d3,sentry-public_key=d7b21f46c2b74e1b80342cb97fde024e,sentry-transaction=/,sentry-sample_rate=0.0 to outgoing request to https://o976653.ingest.sentry.io/api/4504707199270912/store/.
ERROR - [2023-02-20 22:52:02] - django.request.log_response:241 - Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentry-problem/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "sentry-problem/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "sentry-problem/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/views.py", line 85, in sentry_wrapped_callback
    return callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "sentry-problem/sentry_problem/blowup/views.py", line 11, in boom
    request.GET["foo"] = message
    ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
  File "sentry-problem/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 530, in __setitem__
    self._assert_mutable()
  File "entry-problem/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 527, in _assert_mutable
    raise AttributeError("This QueryDict instance is immutable")
AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable
 [sentry] DEBUG: Discarding transaction because sampled = False
[20/Feb/2023 22:52:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145
 [sentry] DEBUG: Sending event, type:null level:error event_id:524b9bd46dac4755add9243e5c118a3f project:4504707199270912 host:o976653.ingest.sentry.io
 [sentry] DEBUG: [Tracing] Adding `sentry-trace` header abb76d466fe34822801a69260476d4ee-b609bdb92b8a0f95- to outgoing request to https://o976653.ingest.sentry.io/api/4504707199270912/store/.
```

I get events for the logger.error, but I get nothing for the 500 that gets thrown and you can see that Snetry is discarding it `because sampled = False`. Sampled isn't one of the config variables (sample_rate is) and even with sample_rate=1.0, it gives this same error.

Does anyone else have sentry flagging 500s?  I've found several forums that talk about it and I've tried things from there, but those things don't help and are a bit old.

Comment: I can reproduce it and would also be interested in how to fix it. Btw, I think sending the error to sentry is most likely not discarded because `sampled = False`. That looks like it only discards the transaction (not the error) because of `sentry-sample_rate=0.0`, which is ok. Did you strip the logs or is there a second `Adding baggage head...` for the second error following?